# How do I do an infinite loop in C# with a 1 minute delay per iteration?

Tags: c#, .net

How do I execute an infinite loop in C# with a 1 minute delay per iteration?

Is there any way to do it *without* using some kind of variable with x++ and setting x to some incredibly large number?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You should post some code.

Comment: You want to loop, doing the same process, with no counter other than this one minute threshold ?

Comment: Huh? System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);

Answer (score 15):

**Solution1 :** 
If you want to `wait` for `1 minute` without hanging your `Main Thread`, it is good to use  `Timer`  Control.

**Step 1:** You need to Subscribe to the `Timer Tick` event.
**Step 2:** Set the `Interval` property of the `Timer` to `60000` milliseconds for raising the event for every  Minute.
**Step 3:** In `Tick Event Handler`  just do ehatever you want to perform.
**Step 4:** you can Call the  `timer1.Stop()` method whenever you want to stop the timer.

**Note** : if you don't `stop` the `timer` it becomes `infinite`.
if you want to `stop` the `timer` you can call `timer1.Stop();`

```
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer1.Interval=60000;//one minute
    timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Start();

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //do whatever you want 
    }
```

**Solution 2:**

**EDIT :** From the below comments : if the OP(Original Poster) is Trying to run this from `Console Application` `System.Timers.Timer` can be used

**Note :** instead of Handling `Tick` Event , OP has to handle the `Elapsed` Event.

**Complete Code:**

```
    class Program
    {
        static  System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            timer1.Interval = 60000;//one minute
            timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
            while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
        }
        static private void timer1_Tick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            //do whatever you want 
            Console.WriteLine("I'm Inside Timer Elapsed Event Handler!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Definitely the cleanest choice, it also moves the timing control outside the functionality that is being executed by the timing

Comment: +1 because while it's not an answer to the precise question he asked, it's an answer to what I think is quite likely the question he really ought to have been asking instead. IYKWIMAITYD.

Comment: This is a good (the correct) answer for WinForms, but there's no indication in the question that he is using WinForms.

Comment: @EdPlunkett you probably meant to use System.Threading.Timer?  This solution is not WinForms specific... at least not when using System.Threading.Timer.

Comment: @Tesserex: i have edited my answer to work with Console Application in `solution2`

Answer (score 4):

```
while (true)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
}
```

Now if we assume you don't want this thread to block and you're ok dealing with threading concerns, you can do something like this:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
       // do your work here
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
    }
});
```

The `Task` will put your work on a ThreadPool thread, so it runs in the background.

You can also look at a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if that's more geared toward what you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(;;)
{
    //do your work
    Thread.Sleep(60000);
}
```

This is not optimal but does exactly what it's asked.

Comment: I don't like "for(;;)" -- too cryptic, I prefer "while (true)".

Comment: @ShellShock Personal opinion - I've used programming languages without while so I'm more used to it.

Answer (score 0):

From a similar question on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/660a1f75-b287-4565-bfdd-75105e0a5527/c-wait-for-x-seconds?forum=netfxbcl):
>

> ```
> System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
> ```
>
> this codes make your application waiting for 5 seconds.

Change the number as necessary for the amount of time you want to sleep for (for one minute, this would be 60000).
You can put this where you want in your while loop

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true){
    Sleep(60000);}
```

This would be a blocking call, so you would want to put it on its own thread or any kind of UI that you would have would hang badly.

[`Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is in the [`System.Threading.Thread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace.