# Infinite while/for loop without hanging in visual studio/C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

What i want to achieve is to loop my code infinite times in my GUI/visual C# as i am reading information through a USB cable.

I have successful read the code but it only shows one reading every time i click the button. I understand that if i want my code to run infinitely, i will need to loop it.

I tried the code below but my program still hangs

```
while(true)
{
     //loop
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500906/how-do-i-do-an-infinite-loop-in-c-sharp-with-a-1-minute-delay-per-iteration/20500970) and wanted to try the timer method however, i do not know where to put this code.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer1.Interval=60000;//one minute
timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
timer1.Start();
```

I am using Microsoft Visual studio 2010, anyone can guide me in using this code?

Comment: If you dont know where to put the timer code, you have other problems, i would suggest doing some basic tutorials and get up to speed on the basics of a C# application

Comment: @Grant Yes i mean by Microsoft visual studio 2010 so sorry about that.

Comment: @MichaelRandall I am actually a beginner and some of my codes were passed down, i understand that i need alot of practice. I wonder if there is any other ways that i can do the infinite loops. Sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please forget about creating such loops in your program, these will kill the UI thread that is actually running your UI, the result will be always bad!

You can run that timer, your code is missing the implementation of timer1_Tick, inside that function, run the code that you want. In your current configuration above, this timer will run every one minute and executes whatever is in timer1_Tick. This is a good [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/run-procedures-at-set-intervals-with-wf-timer-component).

Another option would be to create a thread that does the work for reading the USB and let the UI thread alone. I assume this is a harder option to implement for your so go with the timer option.